# replace string with string in excel

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to compare the string in text file with the first colum in excel sheet
if the string in the file match any value in the first column I want to replace this string with the value in second column and save the changes to the text file

```
import numpy as np
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\\example.xlsx')

ws = wb.active

v = "D:\\A2.txt"
v = open(v).read()
row = 1
cell_addr = "A" + str(row)
next_cell = "B" + str(row)
while ws[cell_addr].value is not None:

    # print(cell_addr, ws[cell_addr].value, type(ws[cell_addr].value))
    j=1
    for i in v:
        if i == ws[cell_addr].value:
            v.replace(i, ws[next_cell].value)
        else:
              print (i)
    with open('D:\\A2.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(i)          

    row += 1
    cell_addr = "A" + str(row)
    next_cell = "B" + str(row)
```

Comment: so what is the problem or error? Don't tell me it's an `openpyxl is not defined` because you forget the import statement

Comment: the error the output does not print correctly for example if  v has ( x, y,z)  i want to compare these with excel file if i find any of them in the fist column then replace it with the value in second column spouse y is in the fist column the i want to replace it and x, z are not in the excel file i want to keep it as its  the final output x,Y1,z  and the changes should save in v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import openpyxl

xlsfile = 'example.xlsx'
txtfile = 'A2.txt'

with open(txtfile, 'r') as f:
    v = f.read().split('\n')

new_v = list(v)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsfile)
ws = wb.active
for cells in ws.rows:
    val = cells[0].value
    if val in v:
        index = v.index(val)
        new_v[index] = cells[1].value

with open(txtfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(new_v))
```

Comment: the  code about dose not change the token in text file  with the value in second column in excle file

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Could you give an example case where this code fails?

Comment: i mean if txtfile  has this token(x y z) and xlsfile have these value in th firset column [x f z] second column have these value [ A B C],  now i want to compare each token in txtfile   with each value in the first culom.  if i find the same string in the firest column then i want to replace the token with the value in the second column. like in the example above [x ,z] is in the first column then i want to replace them with [A C] and the final output will be like [A y C] and i want to save this in same txtfile

Comment: This program does exactly what you described. Have you tried to run it?

Comment: yes, it work but the word in txt file should be in line what about if i whant to tokenize the word and change token

Comment: i have question if i what to encode the excle file : i used  wb = open('D:\\AA.csv','r', encoding='utf-8').read()
reader=csv.reader(wb)    but dose not work
#wb = codecs.openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsfile,'r', encoding="utf-8")
#ws = wb.active

Comment: @somah don't forget to accept the answer if it's working. I'm not sure what do you mean by encode excel file but if you want to read csv file pass `file` object to `csv.reader()` instead of `string`. In other words, remove `.read()` from `wb = open('D:\\AA.csv','r', encoding='utf-8')`. If you need more detail please create new question